# Iterate filters in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have in the view

```
<tr ng-repeat="entry in entryList | myfilter1">
    <td>{{entry.id}}</td>
    <td>{{entry.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Now I want to do something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="entry in entryList | myfilter1">
    <td>{{entry.id}}</td>
    <td>{{entry.name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="entry in entryList | myfilter2">
    <td>{{entry.id}}</td>
    <td>{{entry.name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="entry in entryList | myfilter3">
    <td>{{entry.id}}</td>
    <td>{{entry.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Is there any nice way to iterate filters?

**EDIT**

Here is [link on sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/X0EMswAShlb4Z1NUuVwY?p=preview). Basically, I'm looking for something like `ng-repeat="myfilter in [myfilter1, myfilter2, myfilter3]` (trying this directly didn't succeed - [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/i1M2vxtYFgXA7126sRQx?p=preview))

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean with "iterate filters"?

Comment: if you look on second part then you can note there almost the same parts. The only difference is name of used filter. So, I assume there is kind of way to loop filters like `ng-repeat="myFilter in [myfilter1, myfilter2, myfilter3]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="fil in filters">
   <tr ng-repeat="entry in entryList | filter: fil">
     <td>{{entry.id}}</td>
     <td>{{entry.name}}</td>
   </tr>
</span>
```

And on the controller:

```
$scope.filters = [myfilter1, myfilter2, myfilter3];
```

Note: instead of `<span>` you can use another element tag...

### Edit

If you defined your own filters:

```
<table ng-repeat="fil in filters">
    <tr ng-repeat="entry in fil(entryList)">
    <td>{{entry.id}}</td>
    <td>{{entry.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And on the controller:

```
$scope.filters = [$filter('myfilter1'), $filter('myfilter2')];
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YbFOF2HdDtLO1vcwmZzN?p=preview)**

Comment: Hi. Initially, I had the same idea but it does not work :(  Here is [proof](http://plnkr.co/edit/i1M2vxtYFgXA7126sRQx?p=preview)

Comment: Updated my answer. Check if it helps.